# Pyspark : How I create a column in Pyspak with this condition ? Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

If df.acc = "1" and df.bcc = "1" then "Normal"

If df.acc = "1" and df.bcc = "2" then "Critical"

If df.acc = "1" and df.bcc = "3" then "AOG"

If df.acc = "4" and df.bcc = "1" then "Warranty"

If df.acc = "4" and df.bcc = "2" then "Routine"

If df.acc = "4" and df.bcc = "3" then "Contract"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe like this.

```
+---+---+
|acc|bcc|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  4|  1|
|  4|  2|
|  4|  3|
+---+---+
```

You can create an additional column based on your conditions like so. Note that "Other" is the value entered into the column if none of the conditions are met.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = (df.withColumn("new_column_name", 
    functions.when((df["acc"] == "1") & (df["bcc"] == "1"), "Normal")
             .when((df["acc"] == "1") & (df["bcc"] == "2"), "Critical")
             .when((df["acc"] == "1") & (df["bcc"] == "3"), "AOG")
             .when((df["acc"] == "4") & (df["bcc"] == "1"), "Warranty")
             .when((df["acc"] == "4") & (df["bcc"] == "2"), "Routine")
             .when((df["acc"] == "4") & (df["bcc"] == "3"), "Contract")
             .otherwise("Other")))
```